# Gatling - Custom Validations

Tags: validation, gatling

I am new to gatling and scala.

I want a request to fail if the JSON response didn't match the JSON schema.
This is my schema validator function.

```
 def validateJsonAgainstSchema(jsonResponseExpr:Expression[String], schemaFile:String)(session: Session): Validation[Session] = {

        val jsonResponse=jsonResponseExpr(session)
        val jsonSchema = testUtilsObj.readFile(schemaFile)
        val schema: JsonNode = asJsonNode(parse(jsonSchema))
        val instance: JsonNode = asJsonNode(parse(jsonResponse.get))
        val validator = JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault().getValidator
        val processingReport = validator.validate(schema, instance)

        if (processingReport.isSuccess) {
               Success(session)
             } else {
            println("****validation Failed*******")
            println(processingReport.map(_.asJson()).mkString("\n"))
           Failure(processingReport.map(_.asJson()).mkString("\n"))
        }
      }
```

I call this function in exec block as below, and the gatling test passes even if the function returns failure.

```
 .exec(
        valObj.validateJsonAgainstSchema("${jsonResponse}","Schemas/searchQueryResponse.json") _
      )
```

How to make the call to `validateJsonAgainstSchema` in the request check block? Can some one give me example of implementing custom validations?